# For postproc of graphviz svg I now uses several perl exps with differing input opts. How to combine?

Tags: regex, perl, svg, graphviz, dot

I use `graphviz` to generate SVG graphs, and use some perl expressions (some `-lane`, some `-0pe`) to post-process/slim the `dot` output.

The following shell/perl command pipeline will:

- convert some `<polygons` into `<rect`, because `dot` outputs even perfect rectangles as polygons.
- convert some more polygons, because "clusters" -though rectangular- are layed out differently to "normal" nodes
- removes/rounds some ".9999999" fractions somehow resulting from the first 2 commands...
- rewrites straight lines (h+v) from `<path` to `<line`
- remove empty groups resulting from invisible nodes and paths still being "rendered" to the SVG.
- Ultimately make the file smaller and also easier to read.

How would I optimize this script and/or compact it into less statements under one perl invocation?

```
$ cat Graph.dot.svg |
perl -lane '# Rectangular Nodes: Polygons like DR-DL-UL-UR-DR
/^<polygon( .* )points="([-\d.]*),([-\d.]*) ([-\d.]*),\3 \4,([-\d.]*) \2,\5 \2,\3"(.*)$/
and do {
  $x=($2<$4?$2:$4); $y=($3<$5?$3:$5);
  $w=abs($2-$4); $h=abs($3-$5);
  print "<rect$1x=\"$x\" y=\"$y\" width=\"$w\" height=\"$h\"$6";
} or print $_;' |
perl -lane '# Cluster Nodes -also rects-, but layed out differntly:
/^<polygon( .* )points="([-\d.]*),([-\d.]*) \2,([-\d.]*) ([-\d.]*),\4 \5,\3 \2,\3"(.*)$/
and do {
  $x=($2<$5?$2:$5); $y=($3<$4?$3:$4);
  $w=abs($2-$5); $h=abs($3-$4);
  print "<rect$1x=\"$x\" y=\"$y\" width=\"$w\" height=\"$h\"$6";
} or print $_;
' | perl -pe '# Rounds ".999999" and "\d*[36]99+7" "errors"
/^<rect/ and s/([0-9]+\.)99+/$1+1/e;s/([36])99+7/$1+1/e
' | perl -lane '# Straight vertical lines as paths -> "<line"
print /^<path( .* )d="M([-\d.]*),([-\d.]*)C(([-\d.]*),\3 ?){3}"(.*)$/
  ?"<line$1x1=\"$2\" y1=\"$3\" x2=\"$5\" y2=\"$3\" stroke-width=\"2\"$6" : $_;
' | perl -lane '# Straight horizontal lines as paths -> "<line"
print /^<path( .* )d="M([-\d.]*),([-\d.]*)C(\2,([-\d.]*) ?){3}"(.*)$/
  ?"<line$1x1=\"$2\" y1=\"$3\" x2=\"$2\" y2=\"$5\" stroke-width=\"2\"$6" : $_;
' | perl -0777 -pe '
s/^<!-- [^ ]\* -->\s<g [^<]*<title>[^>]*>\s<\/g>$//mg' > Output.dot.svg
```

Example Input data below generated from graph:

```
graph G {
node[shape=box,height=0,width=0,margin=0]
  subgraph cluster_1 {
    start -- b1;
  }
 rank=same{b1 -- end};
 end [shape=circle];
}
```

with either `dot -Tsvg` or online [here(viz.je)](http://mdaines.github.io/viz.js/)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="89pt" height="105pt"
 viewBox="0.00 0.00 89.29 105.39" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 101.388)">
<polygon fill="white" stroke="none" points="-4,4 -4,-101.388 85.2939,-101.388 85.2939,4 -4,4"/>
<g id="clust1" class="cluster"><title>cluster_1</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="8,-56.5878 8,-89.3878 48,-89.3878 48,-56.5878 8,-56.5878"/>
</g>
<g id="node1" class="node"><title>start</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="40.1012,-81.2889 15.8988,-81.2889 15.8988,-64.6866 40.1012,-64.6866 40.1012,-81.2889"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="28" y="-68.7878" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">start</text>
</g>
<g id="node2" class="node"><title>b1</title>
<polygon fill="none" stroke="black" points="35,-22.5951 21,-22.5951 21,-5.9927 35,-5.9927 35,-22.5951"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="28" y="-10.0939" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">b1</text>
</g>
<!-- start&#45;&#45;b1 -->
<g id="edge1" class="edge"><title>start&#45;&#45;b1</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M28,-64.576C28,-53.7707 28,-33.796 28,-22.8884"/>
</g>
<g id="node3" class="node"><title>end</title>
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="67" cy="-14.2939" rx="14.0907" ry="14.0907"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="67" y="-10.0939" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">end</text>
</g>
<!-- b1&#45;&#45;end -->
<g id="edge2" class="edge"><title>b1&#45;&#45;end</title>
<path fill="none" stroke="black" d="M35.0078,-14.2939C40.8397,-14.2939 46.6716,-14.2939 52.5035,-14.2939"/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

The result after feeding the above input into the perl pipeline (Notice all the polygons and paths have been converted to rectangles and lines.)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="89pt" height="105pt"
 viewBox="0.00 0.00 89.29 105.39" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 101.388)">
<rect fill="white" stroke="none" x="-4" y="-101.388" width="89.2939" height="105.388"/>
<g id="clust1" class="cluster"><title>cluster_1</title>
<rect fill="none" stroke="black" x="8" y="-89.3878" width="40" height="32.8"/>
</g>
<g id="node1" class="node"><title>start</title>
<rect fill="none" stroke="black" x="15.8988" y="-81.2889" width="24.2024" height="16.6023"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="28" y="-68.7878" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">start</text>
</g>
<g id="node2" class="node"><title>b1</title>
<rect fill="none" stroke="black" x="21" y="-22.5951" width="14" height="16.6024"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="28" y="-10.0939" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">b1</text>
</g>
<!-- start&#45;&#45;b1 -->
<g id="edge1" class="edge"><title>start&#45;&#45;b1</title>
<line fill="none" stroke="black" x1="28" y1="-64.576" x2="28" y2="-22.8884" stroke-width="2"/>
</g>
<g id="node3" class="node"><title>end</title>
<ellipse fill="none" stroke="black" cx="67" cy="-14.2939" rx="14.0907" ry="14.0907"/>
<text text-anchor="middle" x="67" y="-10.0939" font-family="Times,serif" font-size="14.00">end</text>
</g>
<!-- b1&#45;&#45;end -->
<g id="edge2" class="edge"><title>b1&#45;&#45;end</title>
<line fill="none" stroke="black" x1="35.0078" y1="-14.2939" x2="52.5035" y2="-14.2939" stroke-width="2"/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I would start by writing a few test cases. Then rewrite each of your one-liners into actual programs that don't have the `-p` or other flags. Then you can turn them into functions inside the same program and refactor them into step by step into something that works over the whole file in one go. Keep using your test cases while you do it.

Comment: 1. Create a variable to store output ($txt).
2. Open and Read file line by line. 
3. For each line
    a. if it matches one of your patterns, then concatenate the replacement string to $txt with a newline.
    b. If it does not match, just concatenate the line ($_) to ($txt).
4. After reading all of the lines, perform a multi-line regexp substitution on $txt to remove the <!-- ... <g> ... blocks.
5. Print $txt